# How can I read Chinese characters correctly using Scanner in Java?

Tags: java

Programming language: Java
Task: designing a hash function that maps Chinese Strings to numbers
Problem: correct reading and displaying of Chinese characters

This is a homework question, but I'm not asking how to do it, just having trouble implementing the reading of Chinese characters.

A short description of my task: to design a hash function to map (Chinese) students' names in our class to their student IDs, and other satellite data (gender, phone and the like).

I'm still thinking about it, but just like other languages, the scope of this involves me using the character encoding of a character to, via the hash function, come up with a unique value, if I'm not mistaken.

Here's what I have to test the validity of this train of thought:

```
// test whether console can read chinese characters
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a Chinese character: ");
int chi = (int)s.next().toCharArray()[0];

System.out.println("\nThe string entered is " + chi);
```

If I use a simple System.out.println("character") statement, the correct character is displayed.

But as seen above, if I use Scanner to read input, I've tried to convert the String into a char array then to its int unicode equivalent, but it comes up with a ridiculous number, and I can't display it correctly.

I realize I can just use this erroneous value to design a hash function, but for the sake of not creating possible collisions (I don't know if these produce UNIQUE erroneous values), and for the sake of learning, could you point out how I might unify input of chinese characters across different machines?

Always grateful for your thoughts. :D

Baggio.

Comment: *"This is a homework question, but I'm not asking how to do it, .."*  I predict you will go far, and gain many allies along the journey. :)

Comment: Why can't you just use the name's `String`'s hashcode directly? Why are you messing about casting `char` to `int`?

Comment: @artbristol I haven't really thought of that...will try that - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-thinking this. Every `String` is already (conceptually) a sequence of characters, including Chinese characters.. Encoding only comes into it when you need to convert it into a bytes, which you don't need to for your assignment. Just use the `String`'s hashcode. In fact, when you create a `HashMap<String,YourObject>`, that's exactly what will happen behind the scenes.

Comment: I haven't gone through the Map class yet and how to use it, but that's a useful pointer, I'll check that out later. And yeah, I probably overcomplicated it, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

When you create a Scanner, you can also tell it which character encoding to use. [Here is the documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that before - I'll check it out.

Comment: this does not work for me when I try to read japanese characters

Comment: @Abi: There are several different and incompatible character encodings which are commonly used for Japanese characters, like Unicode, Shift-JIS, EUC-JP or ISO-2022-JP. Make sure you select the one your characters are in.

Answer (score 3):

When you are not using basic ASCII characters, you need to consider which character set you are using. Most often it will be UTF-8 but other character sets can be used as well.

One thing to keep in mind is that the size of a non-ASCII character can exceed 1 byte. This is true of Chinese characters.

When dealing with multibyte characters, you will need to think in terms of codepoints (which is the integer representing the UTF-8 character) instead of single-byte characters.

Newer versions of Java allow you to iterate over a String using codepoints. Look at the Java API for String.

Comment: `Converting a String to a character array will not work` - that *will* work. Converting it to a *byte* array won't.

Comment: Indeed, if my understanding of what you said is correct, it was strange - for each Chinese character I read using Scanner, and printed out the int equivalent, it was a sequence of three ints - prob. the codepoint you've mentioned. Will keep that in mind, thx!