# Read Japanese Character using Scanner

Tags: java, encoding, java.util.scanner

Possible duplicate:
[How can I read Chinese characters correctly using Scanner in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898123/how-can-i-read-chinese-characters-correctly-using-scanner-in-java)

My input file name may have japanese characters and I am trying to read the file name using Scanner.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"utf-8");
System.out.println("Encoding is :" + Charset.defaultCharset());

System.out.println("Enter the path:");
inputFilePath = sc.nextLine();
```

and if my input is for eg - 漢字

When I print the file name my output is

```
Encoding is :UTF-8
Input File Path:æ¼¢å­—
```

I also tried,

```
byte[] jis = sc.nextLine().getBytes("Shift_JIS");
System.out.println(new String(jis));
```

and My output was

```
Input File Path:??��??�\
```

How can I rectify this?

Comment: but when I am reading the value from the Scanner i am mentioning the enoding as utf-8. I thought that will suffice

Comment: so you are saying jis = inputFilePath.getBytes("UTF-16"); is right? this doesnt work if i give Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); and jis = inputFilePath.getBytes("UTF-16");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Eclipse` is reading from the Console which is set by default as UTF-8. To read the data you need to change the console encoding to Japanese supported encoding.

In the Run Configuration, change the encoding to Japanese supported encoding and try again.

[image]

Comment: yes, when I changed the encoding to UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE, I am able to view the japanese input.Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is misleading, UTF-8 does support Japanese (And any language for that matter) and should be preferred over legacy encodings such as Shift-JIS

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, only issue is you are reading `utf-8` and then converting it to `Shift_JIS` which prints junk characters.

Have you tried using this.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"utf-8");
System.out.println("Encoding is :" + Charset.defaultCharset());

System.out.println("Enter the path:");
String inputFilePath = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input path:" + new String(inputFilePath.getBytes("utf-8")));
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: nope, still getting the gibberish output                       Enter the path:漢字
Input path:æ¼¢å­—

Comment: @Abi, this answer looks right. can you make sure the terminal character encoding is also set to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

This Answer for [Chinese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898123/how-can-i-read-chinese-characters-correctly-using-scanner-in-java)

Every String is already (conceptually) a sequence of characters, including Chinese characters.. Encoding only comes into it when you need to convert it into a bytes, which you don't need to for your assignment. Just use the String's hashcode. In fact, when you create a HashMap, that's exactly what will happen behind the scene