# Special characters not working with StringBuilder.append(String)

Tags: java, string, special-characters, stringbuilder

Part of my code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
sb.append(s);
```

If add

```
System.out.println(sb);
```

on line 5, it will output � if I enter special character (åäö) at line 4:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
```

Why is it behaving like this? Should I use something else to get input from the user?

EDIT: It will output "åäö" corretly if I just append "åäö" to a StringBuild and print it with System.out.println(sb); (where sb is the StringBuilder).

EDIT 2: I am using NetBenas IDE 8.0

EDIT 3: The problem does not seem to be the encoding.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"utf-8");
```

Still gives the same result.

Comment: have you looked for encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IDE are you using. Try set the console to print UTF-8 chars.
If you are using Eclipse go in Run Configurations --> select your Run Configuration --> Under Common tab change the encoding

Comment: It will output "åäö" corretly if I just append "åäö" to a StringBuild and print it with System.out.println(sb);

Comment: Using Eclipse:Delete the file. Copy the same file again. Don't open the file. Right Click on the file --> Properties. Resource --> Text file encoding --> check "Other" with UTF-8. Open the file.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Removing this as this was not correct)

Comment: But are you sure that is the solution? See first edit.

Comment: Can you try open the file with Nodepad++ and Convert to UTF-8

Comment: Give me a moment and I will try

Comment: Which file is it that I should edit? It it is build.xml, then encoding is already UTF-8.

Comment: can you try change Scanner to: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"utf-8"); Here is what I've found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974326/read-japanese-character-using-scanner

Comment: Tried Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"utf-8");, still the same output. I'll read your link and see what they say. Thanks!

Comment: btw I have run your code in Eclipse and it works fine. properly printing åäö

Comment: [Here is the full code.](http://pastebin.com/jZTW3g7G) I'll download Eclipse and give it a try.

Comment: I've run you program here is the output of it: åäö
å
ä
ö
ÅäÖ

Comment: It seems to me that this has to be a problem with NetBeans. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are always encoded as UTF-16 in java. Set the encoding of your console properly. If you are using some IDE then just google on how to set UTF-8 encoding for console

Comment: Looking at build.xml, that seems to be the case already:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>